# Why do Arrays require ClassTags but collections like List do not?

Tags: scala, collections

This works fine:

```
def x[A](a: A) = List(a)
```

No ClassTag available for A:

```
def y[A](a: A) = Array(a)
```

But of course this is kosher:

```
def y[A : ClassTag](a: A) = Array(a)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays preserve their type at runtime, but generic methods lose their genericity at runtime due to type erasure. So, if you're dynamically creating an array at runtime from a generic method, the generic type information has to be preserved. The JVM is not aware of the type due to erasure, but Scala keeps the information around in the form of the ClassTag, allowing you to avoid the erasure problem.

You could cheat by using Java reflection

```
def y[A](a: A, length: Int) = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass, length)
```

but this would be terrible - note that the returned type is Object, not Array[A], due to erasure

```
scala> y("foo", 1)
res2: Object = Array(null)
```

Also note that java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance() returns Object in the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

This makes sense because Java has erasure and doesn't have ClassTags.

Scala has ClassTags, so the array created at runtime can be created with the appropriate type:

```
scala> def y[A : ClassTag](a: A) = Array(a)
y: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Array[A]

scala> y("foo")
res4: Array[String] = Array(foo)

scala> y(1)
res5: Array[Int] = Array(1)
```

Learn more about type erasure on the JVM here (Java examples):

- [Erasure of generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)
- [Erasure of generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)
- [Erasure of bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)
- [Non-reifiable types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html)

Of course, due to erasure, List of A becomes List of AnyRef at runtime, so as long as the type checking is validated at compile time (via generics), the JVM doesn't care at runtime what the types are when the generic object is instantiated.

Comment: but why does Array requires ClassTag while List doesn't? For example, method `empty` in the companion object of Array and List