# Converting scala list to array

Tags: scala, classtag

When I try to do this, it works fine

```
  val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)

  val array = list.toArray
```

But I am trying to understand the implicits that happen behind the scenes. The signature of toArray is

```
[B >: Int](implicit evidence$1 : classTag[B])
```

Any explanation on what's happening would be good to know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919214/why-do-arrays-require-classtags-but-collections-like-list-do-not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Arrays require ClassTags but collections like List do not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919214/why-do-arrays-require-classtags-but-collections-like-list-do-not)